# apply t.test dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am new to programming, and have little idea how to approach this, any help would be much appreciated.

I must use a two-sample t-test to compare two sets of data, `c` and `t`, each of which is divided into 6 sub columns in the same dataframe, in Excel the data appears something like this:

```
name|c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6|t1|t2|t3|t4|t5|t6
```

`"name"` is the same for each row, but differs between rows.
The columns c1-t6 contain numeric values, which differ between each row and column.

Each row must be tested individually, comparing the `c` subgroup to the `t` subgroup.

How would I go about doing this? I'm guessing a loop will be needed?

Comment: Use `Map` to match up the treatment and control columns, like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269163/mapply-unsuccessful-for-columnwise-t-test-of-two-dataframes-r/26269215

Comment: Thankyou, this was very helpful. However using these codes I am getting overall results for the whole columns i.e. the t-statistic of c1, of c2 etc, but I need the results for both each column and row i.e. a result for name 1 c1, name 1 c2 etc, then name 2 c1, name 2 c2 etc for a dataset of about 22,000 names. Maybe the functions described do work this way and I'm implementing them incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the unpaired two group [t-test](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/ttest.html), consider using the [mapply](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/mapply) function, the multivariate version of sapply which applies `FUN` to the first elements of each argument, the second elements, the third elements, and so on.

```
# DF SPLIT BETWEEN EACH CONTROL AND TREATMENT
controls <- df[c(grep("c", names(df)))]        # ALL C COLS
treatments <- df[c(grep("t", names(df)))]      # ALL T COLS

# MAPPLY USING TTEST
tstats_m <- mapply(ttest, var1=controls, var2=treatments)
tstats_m <- as.data.frame(tstats_m)

# MAPPLY USING DEFINED FUNCTION TTEST
tfunc <- function(var1, var2){
            t.test(var1, var2)            
          }
tstats_m <- mapply(tfunc, var1=controls, var2=treatments)
```

Alternatively, below is the traditional `for` loop that iterates results of each test:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(controls){
  print(paste0("Two-sample t-test c", i, " = t", i))
  print(t.test(controls[paste0("c", i)], treatments[paste0("t", i)]))
}
```

Comment: unless you specify var.equal=T, you're performing a welch test not a classic two sample t.test()...

Answer (score 1):

Using @thelatemail's input, you would most likely do the following, illustrated here with a reproducible example. `df`is your data.frame and as I work with `dplyr`, I'll use this here too.

```
require(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
+     name = sample(letters[1:10]),
+     c1 = sample(1:10),
+     c2 = sample(1:10),
+     t1 = sample(1:10), 
+     t2 = sample(1:10))
df
   name c1 c2 t1 t2
1     i  7  3  8  2
2     h  6  4  4  8
3     g  4  6  6  5
4     b  5  1  9 10
5     a  9  5  3  7
6     j  8  9  5  3
7     d 10  8 10  4
8     c  2  2  2  1
9     e  1 10  7  6
10    f  3  7  1  9
df1 <- df %>% select(contains("c"))
df2 <- df %>% select(contains("t"))
Map(t.test, as.data.frame(df1), as.data.frame(df2))
```

But, I'm not entirley sure that's what you want to do, as this seems to loop the function over columns and not rows. Thus, a bit of a hacky solution (please someone show me an easier way), I would do the following:

```
require(tidyr)
df2 <- gather(df, condition, measurement, c1:t2)
df3 <- spread(df2, name, measurement)
df3$condition2 <- ifelse(grepl("c", df3$condition), "c", "t")
#check dimensions of new df3
for(i in 2:11){cat(colnames(df3)[i],'\n')
+                y <- df3[, i]
+                res <- t.test(y~df3$condition2, var.equal=T)
+                print(res)
+ }
```

note: I've added the var.equal=T assuming you want to do a `two sample t.test()`

I believe this gives you the `t.test` for your data you desire.